# How can I compile to assembly with gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

How do I compile to assembly instead of an executable with gcc. I know there is an **-S** flag, but where do I use it in the makefile. For example, if I use flags **-O3 -o exe_name**, where should I put the -S flag?

Comment: Do you mean object file instead of assembly?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I suggest also using `-fverbose-asm` because then the generated assembler has some generated comments which "explains" the code. For example:

```
gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O2 foo.c
```

would generate in `foo.s` (with some comments) the assembler code produced by compiling `foo.c`

And to understand what the GCC optimizations are doing one could even try `-fdump-tree-all` (but this produces *hundreds* of files!).

Comment: Related: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) for more ways to make asm more readable, and an excellent intro video to reading x86 asm, from Matt Godbolt (of online compiler-explorer fame).

Answer (score 32):

You can ask GCC to produce the assembly file, instead of an object file (or an executable).

For instance:

```
gcc -Wall -c test.c
```

Will produce an object file from test.c (test.o).

```
gcc -Wall -o test test.c
```

Will produce an executable file named 'test' from test.c

```
gcc -Wall -S test.c
```

Will produce an assembly file from test.c (test.s)

Comment: Respectfully disagree: you do *compile* to assembly, then *assemble* to an object file. For instance, the documentation for `-S` on my system says `Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble.`

Comment: Why do you say you don't "compile" to assembly? That's exactly what it is doing! Compiling! To machine code aka assembly! After compiling, it's just a matter of writing it in 0-1s or letters.

Comment: In my opinion, compilation means to turn source code into machine code. Assembly is source code, even if very close to machine code.

Comment: @Macmade, compilation can also mean to turn high-level language constructs into low-level opcodes (that, incidentally, can be represented in assembly then converted to machine code). Your mileage may vary (especially with "managed" languages like C#, which compile to CIL then JIT to machine code).

Comment: @Macmade, Isn't the assembly file output from `-S` just a normal text file?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, so?

Comment: @Macmade: for the record, gcc is designed so that the actual compiler (`cc1`) produces asm, which is assembled by a separate assembler.  With `-o`, the front end does this for you, but it is a separate step.  There is no option to go *directly* to machine code, because gcc doesn't have an assembler built-in.  An assembler has to know about object-file formats (ELF, A.OUT, Mach-O, Windows PE, etc.), instruction encoding optimization, branch-displacement optimization, etc.  gcc doesn't even know instruction lengths, it just has heuristics for emitting `.p2align 4,12` / `.p2align 3` for example.

Answer (score 14):

Put it pretty much anywhere.

```
gcc -O3 -S -o output.asm ...
```

will store the generated assemby in `output.asm`.

Comment: by default `-S` writes something like `filename.s` so I don't think that the `-o` parameter is necessary

Comment: Correct, it's only necessary of you want to chose the name of the output file .