# Why does std::tuple break small-size struct calling convention optimization in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, x86, calling-convention, stdtuple

C++ has a small-size struct calling convention optimization where the compiler passes a small-size struct in function parameters as efficiently as it passes a primitive type (say, via registers). For example:

```
class MyInt { int n; public: MyInt(int x) : n(x){} };
void foo(int);
void foo(MyInt);
void bar1() { foo(1); }
void bar2() { foo(MyInt(1)); }
```

`bar1()` and `bar2()` generate almost identical assembly code except for calling `foo(int)` and `foo(MyInt)` respectively. Specifically on x86_64, it looks like:

```
        mov     edi, 1
        jmp     foo(MyInt) ;tail-call optimization jmp instead of call ret
```

But if we test `std::tuple<int>`, it will be different:

```
void foo(std::tuple<int>);
void bar3() { foo(std::tuple<int>(1)); }

struct MyIntTuple : std::tuple<int> { using std::tuple<int>::tuple; };
void foo(MyIntTuple);
void bar4() { foo(MyIntTuple(1)); }
```

The generated assembly code looks totally different, the small-size struct (`std::tuple<int>`) is passed by pointer:

```
        sub     rsp, 24
        lea     rdi, [rsp+12]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 1
        call    foo(std::tuple<int>)
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

I dug a bit deeper, tried to make my int a bit more dirty (This should be close to an incomplete naive tuple impl):

```
class Empty {};
class MyDirtyInt : protected Empty, MyInt {public: using MyInt::MyInt; };
void foo(MyDirtyInt);
void bar5() { foo(MyDirtyInt(1)); }
```

but the calling convention optimization is applied:

```
        mov     edi, 1
        jmp     foo(MyDirtyInt)
```

I have tried GCC/Clang/MSVC, and they all showed the same behavior. ([Godbolt link here](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BWK43YfVeu6iklqnUCj4EZ3y1VknGc7ha85JwWpr1mi2naFW1abbbjbBGTwEfa81kJivCKsHcF4DIpt2eYioAhJAdImt1/akB0nOkPJ4vN6B6zACcEGUFuNN0krbFIhntzv1wkZzfszkAVlzfPx%2Bw7XcJxbXpfWfQ6rBAfRPfVIpj6bg/qFfOjkOR3S6HpMEmSRBk4D9l2/J8OgAaxAQZBgAOmQ9CMMwgA2IRX24D8vx/Ug/z6D8FBADwYJ/Do4FgJA0FrPB2DICgIAYzwmIqYBTlyKgmIHYhyIgBxXyIhxrHSfZXyg0gGKMLQCAAeVoVgpNg0gsCMERgHYUSP3wYhBzwWFMHI9TMB%2BJIDAHaSPyuZQ9KEPAHGISS9CwWzSAIYg8CMWyOhoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFBAJkJyHHIyAOlQOt/DMgBaRTJDIxJkg0CBzDqUxBkkUhzGaco4kGLwfD8OhCqQkrQlq2hypiCoILyIy6CKWp9GyQQlHyFIahKawyjauISsaXqghyRQRta1pJEkDoFBA3ouGfV930/RySJ%2BAAOLC0qw7hxmAZBkHGU4UM4cYIFwQgSHAyDxz0RjmJeplxgAmQ5GgvTzVIRDkLQzDweQnCXz6fDdvUkiyIorzAdIWjEBALoCAeAhyEodjOJcXJMHwIhCdIQLGBYXSwoAd1czx/Nwt8CL218hjumnCAQX4jpOs6Lqum6ZKouDgaQ1CIYhpnYcI39X0RyjAa2vosrhoiEeR2CgZMwT/BAbggA%3D%3D%3D)) So I guess this must be something in the C++ standard? (I believe the C++ standard doesn't specify any ABI constraint, though?)

I'm aware that the compiler should be able to optimize these out, as long as the definition of `foo(std::tuple<int>)` is visible and not marked noinline. But **I want to know which part of the standard or implementation causes the invalidation of this optimization.**

FYI, in case you're curious about what I'm doing with `std::tuple`, I want to create a wrapper class (i.e. the *strong typedef*) and don't want to declare comparison operators (operator<==>'s prior to C++20) myself and don't want to bother with Boost, so I thought `std::tuple` was a good base class because everything was there.

---

OP's Edit:
[Daniel Langr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580083/daniel-langr) has [pointed the root cause in the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63723752). Please also check the comments under that answer.
And there is already [a fix for this committed one year afterwards](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/0187e0d7360f327f88d8b2294668669306ae4630) and is merged to gcc since the release of gcc 12.1.0, which is almost 2 years afterwards.

Comment: I suspect it's the `std::tuple`'s user-defined copy/move constructors that affect the behavior here. But I can't tell you what in the ABI it's interacting with here.

Comment: Normally it’s a nontrivial destructor which causes this behaviour, but the `std::tuple<int>` destructor should be trivial.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Anyway, adding user-defined destructor to `MyInt` has the same effect: https://godbolt.org/z/s4zzcx.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, that’s what I said. It seems that supplying a custom version of *any* of copy constructor, move constructor or destructor causes an ABI change. I guess this makes sense.

Comment: I think it worth mentioning that this is just another case of what Chandler Carruth talked about in CppCon 2019, "there is no zero-cost abstraction". His example was about `std::unique_ptr<T>` but the cases are very similar. https://youtu.be/rHIkrotSwcc?t=1050

Comment: @YehezkelB. I am not sure this is the same case. With libc++, you get passing by registers. It seems to me more like a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: OK, not exactly the same, because `tuple<int>` d-tor is trivial, while `unique_ptr`'s isn't, so in `tuple` case it depends on the way the implementation handles copy/move c-tors, but for `unique_ptr` there is no other option. But the reasoning behind it is still similar.

Comment: duplicates: [Is returning a 2-tuple less efficient than std::pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46901697/995714), [Why is std::pair faster than std::tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26863852/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is returning a 2-tuple less efficient than std::pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901697/is-returning-a-2-tuple-less-efficient-than-stdpair)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71301

Answer (score 13):

It seems to be a matter of ABI. For instance, the [Itanium C++ ABI reads](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#calls):

> If the parameter type is **non-trivial for the purposes of calls**, the caller must allocate space for a temporary and pass that temporary by reference.

And, [further](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#non-trivial):

> A type is considered **non-trivial for the purposes of calls** if it has a **non-trivial copy constructor, move constructor**, or destructor, or all of its copy and move constructors are deleted.

The same requirement is in [AMD64 ABI Draft 1.0](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf).

For instance, in **libstdc++**, `std::tuple` has non-trivial move constructor: https://godbolt.org/z/4j8vds. The Standard prescribes [both copy and move constructor as defaulted](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.cnstr), which is satisfied here. However, at the same time, `tuple` [inherits from `_Tuple_impl`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/tuple#L595) and [`_Tuple_impl` has a user-defined move constructor](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/tuple#L442). Consequenlty, move constructor of `tuple` itself cannot be trivial.

On the contrary, in **libc++**, both copy and move constructors of `std::tuple<int>` are trivial. Therefore, the argument is passed in a register there: https://godbolt.org/z/WcTjM9.

As for **Microsoft STL**, `std::tuple<int>` is trivially neither copy-constructible nor move-constructible. It even seems to break the C++ Standard rules. `std::tuple` is defined recursively and, at the end of recursion, `std::tuple<>` specialization defines [non-defaulted copy constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/tuple#L210). There is a comment about this issue: `// TRANSITION, ABI: should be defaulted`. Since `tuple<>` has no move constructor, both copy and move constructors of `tuple<class...>` are non-trivial.

Comment: So is `libstdc++` non-compliant here? [gasp]

Comment: @underscore_d Why? The Standard only says that the move constructor of `std::tuple` must be defined as defaulted. Which is satisfied by libstdc++.

Comment: Your 2nd sentence contradicts your own post.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Don't understand. In libstdc++, `std::tuple` has defaulted move constructor, according to the Standard. At the same time, `std::tuple` inherits from `_Tuple_impl`. Since `_Tuple_impl` has user-defined move constructor, the move constructor of `std::tuple` isn't trivial. Even if it's defined as defaulted.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oh, you are saying those constructors are defaulted in class `std::tuple` indeed, but not in its base classes. My mistake.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I reworded the explanation in the answer to make it hopefully more clear in this context :).

Comment: I wonder why `stdlibc++` doesn't `default` the copy and move constructors of the base classes? Make it `constexpr` and conditionally `noexcept`, fine, but `default` the implementation. And now this would be an ABI breaking change. As it stands now it is making mockery out of the standard.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It even seems that a [relevant patch has been proposed](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/patch/alpine.DEB.2.02.1605232038220.30609@laptop-mg.saclay.inria.fr/), but not accepted because of breaking backward compatibility regarding calling conventions.

Comment: I thought the failure of such optimization should be related to std library implementation, so I switched between compilers on godbolt. But I never knew clang on godbolt was using libstdc++ by default and in order to use libc++ the corresponding argument must be provided.

Comment: ABI stability fundamentalists are ruining C++ once again. :-(

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @StoryTeller it might be related to a user defined move constructor inside `std::tuple` that causes this behavior.

See for example: https://godbolt.org/z/3M9KWo

Having user defined move constructor leads to the *non-optimized* assembly:

```
bar_my_tuple():
        sub     rsp, 24
        lea     rdi, [rsp+12]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 1
        call    foo(MyTuple<int>)
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

In libcxx for example the copy and move constructors are declared as default both [for `tuple_leaf`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/tuple#L257) and [for `tuple`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/tuple#L666), and you get the small-size struct call convention optimization [for `std::tuple<int>`](https://godbolt.org/z/4MKqzd) but [not for `std::tuple<std::string>`](https://godbolt.org/z/Ec4j6P) which is holding a non trivially moveable member and thus becomes naturally non trivially moveable by itself.

Comment: You need to tell the compiler to use libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/WcTjM9. By default, clang on Compiler Explorer uses libstdc++.

Comment: @DanielLangr hey that's great! it actually presents that for libc++ `std::tuple<int>` is move constructible and thus it has the small-size struct call convention optimization!