# Type-traits for handling structs in Windows x64 calling convention

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm trying to figure out how to detect if a certain c++-pass can be passed directly in a register, or whether an address has to be passed in the x64-calling convention.

For reference, I have my own compiler that generates native code, for a custom scripting-language. This code is interfacing with a c++-application, and currently only supports x64/windows, on the MSVC compiler. Previously, I've used wrappers/abstractions for a lot of things, for example a custom Stack-class for passing and popping parameters, but I'm in the process of handling all calls natively - so I have to get the x64 calling convention right.

There are two cases, passing parameters in, and returning them. Let's start with return, as I think I've got that one mostly right already.

**Return-values:**

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170) mentions:

> User-defined types can be returned by value from global functions and
> static member functions. To return a user-defined type by value in
> RAX, it must have a length of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits. It must
> also have no user-defined constructor, destructor, or copy assignment
> operator. It can have no private or protected non-static data members,
> and no non-static data members of reference type. It can't have base
> classes or virtual functions. And, it can only have data members that
> also meet these requirements. (This definition is essentially the same
> as a C++03 POD type. Because the definition has changed in the C++11
> standard, we don't recommend using std::is_pod for this test.)
> Otherwise, the caller must allocate memory for the return value and
> pass a pointer to it as the first argument. The remaining arguments
> are then shifted one argument to the right. The same pointer must be
> returned by the callee in RAX.

So they say you cannot use std::pod, but don't offer an alternative. Kay? From just reading those requirements, I've been able to come up with the following trait:

```
template <typename T>
concept CanBeReturnedInRAX = 
    std::is_trivially_constructible_v<T> &&  
    std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T> && 
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && 
    std::is_standard_layout_v<T> &&
    sizeof(T) <= 8;
```

So the **first question** is: Is this trait correct? If not, did I miss something? It seems to be handling a lot of cases that I have correctly, but it does not express the documentation 1:1, and I want to avoid some edge-cases.

**Parameter-passing**

I'm a bit lost here. MSDN says:

> Structs and unions of size 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, and __m64 types, are
> passed as if they were integers of the same size. Structs or unions of
> other sizes are passed as a pointer to memory allocated by the caller.
> For these aggregate types passed as a pointer, including __m128, the
> caller-allocated temporary memory must be 16-byte aligned.

Here, no actual requirements are specified, it only says that **structs** of certain sizes are passed as-if they were integers. But then it talkes about "aggregate types" - so what types does that actually entail? It seems to be less restrictive than the return-values, as the following type seems to be passed in-register (but cannot be returned in one):

```
struct YieldConfigBase {};

struct AE_API YieldConfigFull final :
    public impl::YieldConfigBase
{ 
    constexpr YieldConfigFull(bool overwrite, bool isBlocking) noexcept :
        overwrite(overwrite), isBlocking(isBlocking) {}

    bool overwrite;
    bool isBlocking;
};
```

Even though it does not fulfill the trait that I assumed could be used due to the description (std::is_aggregate). Though there is definately some restriction, because the following type requires being passed by address:

```
template<typename Supplier>
class DynamicEnum final
{
public:
    using Type = typename Supplier::Type;

    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<Type>, "Type must be an integral value.");

    constexpr DynamicEnum(void) noexcept :
        m_value(0) {}
    constexpr DynamicEnum(const DynamicEnum& en) noexcept :
        m_value(en.m_value) {}
    constexpr DynamicEnum(Type value) noexcept :
        m_value(value) {}   
    template<typename OtherType>
    constexpr DynamicEnum(const DynamicEnum<OtherType>& other) = delete;

private:

    Type m_value;
};
```

Now the main difference is both the private member, as well as an existing copy-constructor, as well as some additional constructors.

So my **second question**: What trait can be used to determine whether a type can be passed in a register in x64? std::is_standard_layout seems not to be the trick, the only thing I can think of right now is std::is_trivially_copyable, at least based on my two types. However, since this is not at all what the documentation says, and since I don't want to have to guess a ton of corner cases myself, I'd appreciate if someone who knows what's expected for the calling convention to clear things up for me.

Comment: Related for x86-64 System V (all mainstream non-Windows systems): [C++ on x86-64: when are structs/classes passed and returned in registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42411819) .  And [Is returning a 2-tuple less efficient than std::pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46901697) re: the C++-ABI used on top of C ABIs by GCC/Clang which decides what makes an object require an address and thus have to be passed in memory somewhere.  MSVC may have slightly different criteria, IDK.

Comment: Also [Why does std::tuple break small-size struct calling convention optimization in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63719249) has a more recent and concise answer about what "non-trivial for the purposes of calls" means for the Itanium C++ ABI (originally developed for IA-64, widely used by GCC/Clang on other platforms since it's just rules for mapping C++ to a C ABI, not necessarily Itanium).  Again, IDK if MSVC (and GCC/clang targeting Windows) use the same rules.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh god I don't even wanna talk about std::tuple. I used this to pass multi-returns (which were internally unfolded, manually), and I just learned the other day how it doesn't guarantee shit about it's layout. Had to make my own slighty-more standard conformant tuple, that at least has elements in order and let's me reliably query their offsets... jesus.

Comment: @Juliean There isn't any guarantee on layout for almost any type in the standard library. Technically not even `std::array` is guaranteed to have the obvious layout. Really the only exception is probably `std::complex` which is guaranteed to look like an array of two floating-points.

Comment: @user17732522 I was kind of aware of that; tuple is just way worse because there is not even any real way to get an offset to it's members - even if it's just for your local configuration and non-portable. std::pair at least from what I've read is standard-layout; and you can use offsetof. tuple for my use-case just needed to be replaced.

Comment: @user17732522 but there's no simple viable implementation of `std::array` that is not std layout. Aggregate initialization constraint and `data` member function spec imply a certain implementation, and I can't imagine any other implementation that satisfies them.

Comment: @Red.Wave The way the standard specifies it, `std::array` could potentially have a second member after the actual array, so that its size will be unexpected. It could also have an alignment requirement larger than necessary. There is room to argue what exactly could be allowed by the standard (there are stackoverflow questions about it), but my point is that the standard never spells out any layout requirement. Any such restriction would be indirect by the fact that only certain implementations satisfy the other requirements for the type.

Comment: @Red.Wave And in case of length zero there are actually different choices made for the layout in different standard library implementations.

Comment: @user17732522 *"could potentially have a second member after the actual array"*. That's incorrect assumption; it violates the aggregateinitialization constraints, because `array` should be initializable by an initializer of at most `N`(==size) elements. A second member violates that, because you can pass the default init for it as an excess element. Alignment assumption also has no practical benefits; I have yet to see any crazy implementation that does it. Normally the alignment of its only member would not exceed that of the elements. That's just an extra pessimistic assumption.

Comment: And the 0 length is a special case either way. Because the implementation must also define its meaning. Don't use it, and you are fine.

Comment: @Red.Wave The relevant sentence in the standard is https://eel.is/c++draft/array#overview-2 and it isn't all that clear whether "_can [...] with up to N elements_" does or doesn't require the initialization to be ill-formed with more elements in the aggregate initializer. Anyway, that's a topic that's already been argued about in other questions on this site. And of course any implementation violating the layout/alignment assumptions would be insane. I only took it as the most extreme example to demonstrate that the standard doesn't make explicit layout requirements for the library.

Comment: @user17732522 **up to** doesn't need further clarification. It literally means **no more than**. My point is, sometimes there's no need to be explicit about definitions and parties referencing lack of explicitness are generally making excuses to violate std. For the specific case of `array` the only unclear part is its alignment.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the calling convention can obviously differ between compilers/platforms. I assume you are interested only in the MSVC one for x64.

> So the first question is: Is this trait correct? If not, did I miss something? It seems to be handling a lot of cases that I have correctly, but it does not express the documentation 1:1, and I want to avoid some edge-cases.

No, it is not correct and it is impossible to determine this property with standard C++ features.

For example, `std::is_standard_layout` doesn't match the requirements that you are trying to combine. `std::is_standard_layout` only requires that all non-static data members have the *same* access specifier, not that it must be `public`. `std::is_standard_layout` also permits base classes as long as all non-static data members are directly in the same class in the hierarchy.

Furthermore, you check whether the default constructor exists and is trivial, but the requirement states that *no* constructor must be user-defined. You only check one specific argument list. Also, it doesn't state anywhere that a default constructor must be present and usable at all.

You also check that the type is trivially-copyable, but that isn't actually what is required according to the quote. It says that no copy constructor and copy assignment must be user-defined. The requirements for trivially-copyable are quite different. They also check e.g. move assignment.

Replacing it with `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible` or similar won't help you either, because a type can have a trivial copy constructor but not be trivially copy-constructible (e.g. if the copy constructor is user-declared with parameter type `T&` instead of `const T&` and explicitly-defaulted).

Your checks will also fail if the tested members functions are `private` or `protected`, although nothing requires them to be `public` in order to pass by register.

These are only some problems I see. I am sure there are more.

---

> So my second question: What trait can be used to determine whether a type can be passed in a register in x64?

While the requirements you quoted seem to only consider C types and are therefore incomplete, I am pretty sure that again there will be no trait in the C++ standard library that will be able to determine MSVC's ABI decision.

---

Since C++17 the C++ standard effectively limits what types compilers may pass in registers because of mandatory copy elision rules. The exceptions to the mandatory copy elision are specified in [[class.temporary]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.temporary#3). Effectively only types matching these requirements, i.e. trivial non-deleted destructor, only trivial eligible copy/move constructors and at least one eligible copy or move constructor, may be passed in registers.

But the concrete subset that will be passed in registers is up to the ABI. Unfortunately I am not aware of a complete specification for MSVC's C++ or C ABIs and I don't know them well enough to answer your questions more specifically.

Comment: That doesn't sound very good. I'm just wondering now what my options are, and how other languages deal with this type of interfacing with the ABI. It's an ABI after all, what good is it if I can't properly decide how to call methods from my own code? I guess, since I do only care for MSVC atm, I'd need to get someone who know this ABI more specifically, preferably someone from Microsoft directly to answer this :/

Comment: @Juliean: Often foreign-function stuff between languages restricts to plain C, like `extern "C"`.  If you're interfacing with hand-written asm, you can always just look at compiler-generated asm for a test caller to see how any given function should be called.  That should be stable at least until the compiler / C++ library's next ABI version when they change all the things they've been putting off for the sake of binary compat.

Comment: @PeterCordes Restricting to C is no option for me, I'm writing very modern c++23 and allow binding functions taking things like std::string_view as parameters natively. I do look at ASM, I just need a (somewhat) stable way to determine whether foo(A a) and bar(B b) pass its parameter by register or not - I can look at the asm again, but I need to come up with some sort of trait to be able to tell my bind/code-generator "this struct, pass by register; that struct, pass by value", without hardcoding all possible structs.

Comment: FWIW the traits I have right now seem to work so far (std::is_trivial_copyable, I used for parameter-passing) - but as has been pointed out, they don't cover any case. But maybe I'll have to live with that for now and adjust as needed.

Comment: @Juliean If you are trying to pass standard library object across that foreign function interface, then you'll have even more trouble. C ABIs are generally pretty stable. Core C++ ABIs in the case of GCC/Clang at least are also pretty stable and specified as the Itanium C++ ABI. E.g. for GCC you can get a list of all breaking changes in the documentation of the `-fabi-version` option [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html).

Comment: @Juliean But the C++ standard library ABI is not generally stable and isn't compatible between different implementations at all (e.g. libstdc++ from GCC and libc++ form LLVM/Clang are not at all ABI compatible, neither are MSVC on Windows and Clang/libc++ on Windows even with Clang being able to compile for the MSVC ABI).

Comment: @Juliean For example for libstdc++ the ABI compatibility policy and breaks are documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) and that gets rather complicated quickly. Only one direction of compatibility is (usually) guaranteed: Increasing the version of the standard library shared library won't break programs compiled against an old one.

Comment: But because MSVC isn't so clearly documented and because I don't use it, I don't know whether its core ABIs are also stable or how they differ from the Itanium C++ ABI, or what their standard library implementation's policies on ABI stability/compatibility are.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm aware of stability/compatibility issues, though this specifically is not a problem. Briefly, I'm using a system where all code is compiled on the target-platform/compiler; and the specific custom-generated code in question is also always generated on a matching version fo the compiler. So all I really need is to identity the ABI/convention at that point in time, and it'll work for my specific case.

Comment: @Juliean I think that's only going to work by parsing the C++ code (e.g. using LLVM/Clang tooling) and then manually checking the specific ABI's conditions over the AST. (Since Clang supports MSVC's ABI as far as I know, maybe it has the conditions for it already implemented, so that it can be easily used in tooling.) Or maybe MSVC/Clang have some compiler-specific built-in or something that is able to tell how the type will be passed.

Comment: @Juliean E.g. probably https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CodeGen_2MicrosoftCXXABI_8cpp.html#a1c074191f040916bce669223cdc201c0 for clang in combination with its call sites in the same file.

Comment: @user17732522 Specifically isTrivialForMSVC from the clang-doc seems to not be it, as it returns false in case of a base-class; while my own type with a base get's passed in a register. Maybe it's a combination though, as you said - I'll check it out in detail later, thanks!

Comment: @Juliean Yes, that seems to be only for return type passing. As your quote at the beginning states, for return type passing a class with bases is passed indirectly. Looks to me like getRecordArgABI is for argument passing. And for the return type there are additional conditions in classifyReturnType.