# is there is a compiler which convert c++ code into mips assembly language

Tags: c++, mips

Hi I am student and learning mips assembly language, I am curios that is there is any compiler which convert c++ code into mips assembly language, the IDE which i use for coding for mips is Mars. Is there anyway that I write code for c++ and it will automatically convert that code in to mips as i write in mars.
thanks

Comment: Yes, of course, there is a GCC port for that, and no doubt proprietary ones as well. Off topic.

Comment: Related: [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444)

Answer (score 2):

At least, gcc supports MIPS.

A convenient way to try it with small programs could be Godbolt's Compiler Explorer

See this: https://godbolt.org/z/UGzp4r

Comment: Other handy reading: [How can I compile to assembly with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021874/how-can-i-compile-to-assembly-with-gcc)