# Converting my C++ Program to ARM Assembly

Tags: c++, arm

I have been assigned to convert this program to arm assembly v8.

```
int power(int x, int y){
    if (x == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (y < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (y == 0){
        return 1;
        
    }
    else {
        return x * power(x, y - 1);
    }
}
```

Although I'm not very familiar with ARM assembly language and would like to know where to start.

I have attempted to research a bit on this but ultimately found very little on the internet about ARM.

Comment: This is very easy.  Tell your compiler to print out the assembly language for each function as it compiles.  Sometimes it's called a list file.  Look up the compiler commands, as the commands may be different for each compiler.

Comment: Or... use any of a number of interactive sites that [do it for you](https://godbolt.org/z/5fs5c64GW)

Comment: "How can I get started" questions are not a good fit for this site, sorry.  I would suggest talking to your instructor or tutor, reviewing class notes, etc.

Comment: Note that ARMv8 includes two entirely different instruction sets, AArch32 and AArch64.  A good start would be to figure out which one is being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

The magic command is `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -S -O2 -march=armv8-a power.c`.

- I used `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` since I work on an X86-64 machine and `gcc` does not have ARM targets available. If you are on an arm system, you should be able to use regular `gcc` instead. If not it will error, but no harm done.
- `-S` tells gcc to output assembly.
- The `-O2` is optional and just helps to optimize the code slightly and reduce debug clutter from the result.
- `-march=armv8-a` tells it to use the ARM v8 target while compiling. I chose `armv8-a` somewhat arbitrarily. According to the docs all of the ARM v8 are `armv8-a`, `armv8.1-a`, `armv8.2-a`, `armv8.3-a`, `armv8.4-a`, `armv8.5-a`, `armv8.6-a`, `armv8-m.base`, `armv8-m.main`, and `armv8.1-m.main`. I have no idea what the differences are so you may want to choose a different one.
- `power.c` just tells it which file to compile. Since we don't specify an output file (Ex: `-o output.asm`), the assembly will be outputted to `power.s`.

If you are not compiling on an `arm` machine that has provides the desired target with regular `gcc`, you can use `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` instead. If you do not have it installed, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

#### Output

If anyone is curious, this is the output I received when I tried it on my machine.

```
        .arch armv8-a
        .eabi_attribute 20, 1
        .eabi_attribute 21, 1
        .eabi_attribute 23, 3
        .eabi_attribute 24, 1
        .eabi_attribute 25, 1
        .eabi_attribute 26, 2
        .eabi_attribute 30, 2
        .eabi_attribute 34, 1
        .eabi_attribute 18, 4
        .file   "testing.c"
        .text
        .align  2
        .global power
        .syntax unified
        .arm
        .fpu softvfp
        .type   power, %function
power:
        @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
        @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
        @ link register save eliminated.
        clz     r2, r0
        mov     r3, r0
        lsr     r2, r2, #5
        orrs    r2, r2, r1, lsr #31
        bne     .L4
        cmp     r1, #0
        mov     r0, #1
        bxeq    lr
.L3:
        subs    r1, r1, #1
        mul     r0, r3, r0
        bne     .L3
        bx      lr
.L4:
        mov     r0, #0
        bx      lr
        .size   power, .-power
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

#### How can I get started.

Here is my thought process for how I was able to solve this problem. Looking at the problem I could tell it would probably be in two parts:

1. **How can that code be compiled to assembly?**

   For the first part I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8023149/5987669) which provided the command `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O2 foo.c`. After testing it, I decided to remove the `-fverbose-asm` since only seemed to provide clutter for a program this small.
2. **How can I set the compiler target to ARM v8?**

   After a quick google search I found that `gcc` lets you specify the target architecture with `-march=xxx`. My next step was to find a list of ARM architectures that I could select from. After finding [gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html), I selected `armv8-a` since it sounded the most correct. When I tried it out, `gcc` told me that the target architecture could not be found. This was not really a surprise since I am on x86-64 and usually compilers come with the compatible targets to reduce the space required. I knew this likely meant I would need to identify the `apt` package which provided the arm targets so I searched around until I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/250721) which filled in the rest of the information I needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/noscript/c++) is the friend in a such simple cases.

ARMv8-a Clang Assembly with the compiler option -O1 for keeping the recursion:

```
# Compilation provided by Compiler Explorer at https://godbolt.org/
power(int, int):                             // @power(int, int)
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-32]!           // 16-byte Folded Spill
        str     x19, [sp, #16]                  // 8-byte Folded Spill
        mov     x29, sp
        mov     w19, w0
        mov     w0, wzr
        cbz     w19, .LBB0_5
        tbnz    w1, #31, .LBB0_5
        cbz     w1, .LBB0_4
        sub     w1, w1, #1
        mov     w0, w19
        bl      power(int, int)
        mul     w0, w0, w19
        b       .LBB0_5
.LBB0_4:
        mov     w0, #1
.LBB0_5:
        ldr     x19, [sp, #16]                  // 8-byte Folded Reload
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], #32             // 16-byte Folded Reload
        ret
```

ARM GCC (linux) Assembly with the compiler option -O1 for keeping the recursion:

```
# Compilation provided by Compiler Explorer at https://godbolt.org/
power(int, int):
        push    {r4, lr}
        mov     r4, r0
        clz     r0, r0
        lsrs    r0, r0, #5
        orrs    r3, r0, r1, lsr #31
        it      ne
        movne   r0, #0
        beq     .L6
.L1:
        pop     {r4, pc}
.L6:
        movs    r0, #1
        cmp     r1, #0
        beq     .L1
        subs    r1, r1, #1
        mov     r0, r4
        bl      power(int, int)
        mul     r0, r4, r0
        b       .L1
```

ARM GCC (none) Assembly with the compiler option -O1 for keeping the recursion:

```
# Compilation provided by Compiler Explorer at https://godbolt.org/
power(int, int):
        push    {r4, lr}
        mov     r4, r0
        rsbs    r0, r0, #1
        movcc   r0, #0
        orrs    r3, r0, r1, lsr #31
        movne   r0, #0
        beq     .L6
.L1:
        pop     {r4, lr}
        bx      lr
.L6:
        cmp     r1, #0
        moveq   r0, #1
        beq     .L1
        sub     r1, r1, #1
        mov     r0, r4
        bl      power(int, int)
        mul     r0, r4, r0
        b       .L1
```

ARM64 GCC Assembly with the compiler option -O1 for keeping the recursion:

```
# Compilation provided by Compiler Explorer at https://godbolt.org/
power(int, int):
        cmp     w1, 0
        ccmp    w0, 0, 4, ge
        bne     .L9
        mov     w0, 0
        ret
.L9:
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -32]!
        mov     x29, sp
        str     x19, [sp, 16]
        mov     w19, w0
        mov     w0, 1
        cbnz    w1, .L10
.L1:
        ldr     x19, [sp, 16]
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 32
        ret
.L10:
        sub     w1, w1, #1
        mov     w0, w19
        bl      power(int, int)
        mul     w0, w19, w0
        b       .L1
```

Comment: By the way, these are heavily optimized: the compiler has optimized out the tail recursion altogether and made it iterative instead.  If you hand in such code, it will be obvious that you didn't write it yourself.